# XSD Alternative for union

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm working on a xsd and my system poses restriction on the usage of the element `<union>`. Below is the code snippet:

```
<xsd: element name = 'CRN' minOccurs = "1">
  <xsd: simpleType>
   <xsd:union memberTypes = "fps:nonNegativeMax999IntType fps:FullPaymentSubmission_XType"/>
  /xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name = "FullPaymentSubmission_XType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
   <xsd:enumeration value = "X"/>
  </xsd:restriction> 
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name = "nonNegativeMax999IntType ">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:nonNegativeInteger">
   <xsd:maxInclusive value = "9999"/>
  </xsd:restriction> 
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Please can someone suggest an alternative for this where I can avoid using `<union>` in my xsd ?

Comment: It is difficult if you really want to allow the string value `X` and the integers from 0 to 9999, but if you use a single simpleType deriving from `xs:string` where you enumerate all options (`<xsd:enumeration value="X"/><xsd:enumeration value="0"/><xsd:enumeration value="1"/>...<xsd:enumeration value="9999"/>`). You might want to generate the code for all those integer values for instance. Or you could try to write a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSD,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="r">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{1,4}"/>
        <xs:pattern value="X"/>
        <xs:pattern value="Y"/>
        <xs:pattern value="Z"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

will allow `CRN` to be up to 4 digits or `X` or `Y` or `Z`.  You can adjust the regex for any other requirements such as an optional leading `+` or excluding leading `0`s if necessary.